# How do I fit an input with shape (128,224,224,3) into ResnetV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello I am new to tensorflow and I am currently having an issue with using Keras's Resnet50_V2 model. The acceptable input to the Resnet layer is only (224,224,3) while my images are in batches of 128. I can only provide a snippet of this part of the code but the error I'm getting is this

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1_pad" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 128, 224, 224, 3)
```

Here is the Code Snippet. Would I have to unbatch my data so that instead of (128,224,224,3) It would be 128x(224,224,3)?

```
    BATCH_SIZE=128
    resnet_shape=(224,224,3)
    gen = data_batch_loader(mdl_train,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    mode=mode,
    output_shape=resnet_shape,
    crop_shape=cropped_shape,
    spline_order=spline_order)
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    count=0
    for i,j in gen:
        x_train.append(i)
        y_train.append(j)
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)

    x_in = tf.keras.Input(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(BATCH_SIZE,)+resnet_shape)
    resnet_model = tf.keras.Sequential()   
    pre_trained_model = ResNet50V2(include_top=True,input_tensor=x_in,
    classes=NUM_CLASSES,weights=None)
    resnet_model.add(pre_trained_model)
    resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

    resnet_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss=cce,metrics=['accuracy'])
    resnet_model.summary()
    history = resnet_model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=10)
```

Comment: A common misconception, do not include batch size in input layer. It should be `shape=resnet_shape`

Comment: The problem is not the batch size, but the input shape itself. Convolutional neural networks with color channels take inputs tensors with shape `(batch size, y, x, c)`, whereas you have provided an input with shape `(None, batch size, x, y, c)`. Check the torch documentation but that extra dimension `None` should be pretty easy to get rid of.

Comment: hey guys I realize that in this line of code, I add an extra dimension to my dataset. It becomes (38,128,224,224,3). It seems I might have to do a for loop to train then. Since 38 is the # of 128 batches there are if that make sense.


```
    for i,j in gen:

        x_train.append(i)

        y_train.append(j)

    x_train = np.array(x_train)

    y_train = np.array(y_train)
```

Comment: Why are you doing batching yourself? Keras can do it directly in your data, this why you get errors, simply do not batch the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- According to the keras official documentation, Input_shape only to be
  specified if include_top is False otherwise the input shape has to be
  (224, 224, 3) with channels_last data format or (3, 224, 224) with
  channels_first data format.
- It should have exactly 3 input channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 32. For example(200, 200, 3) would be one valid value. If you want to specify the batch size you can specify it while model training. Thank You!